# Split comma delimited string

Tags: r

I have a string in R in the following form:

```
"AAAAA","BBBBB","CCCCC",..
```

And i want to convert it to a standard typical R vector containing the same string elements ("AAAAA", "BBBBB", etc.):

```
vector<-c("AAAAA","BBBBB","CCCCC",..)
```

I've read that `strsplit` could do it, but haven't managed to achieve it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

strsplit gives you back a list of the character vectors, so if you want it in a single vector, use unlist as well.
So,

```
    unlist(strsplit(string, ","))
```

Comment: or `strsplit(string, ",")[[1]]`

Comment: When i use it it says Error in strsplit(string, ",") : non-character argument

Comment: What's the result of class(string)? What's the result of strsplit(as.character(string), ",")?

Comment: Let me see, i was using toString with string.... when i convert it with as.character, string turns into "0"

Comment: It didn't work also, but i found another workaround for what i was trying to achieve in the long term, thanks anyway!